# Keep-Alive in SailsJs

Tags: node.js, sails.js, keep-alive

I would like to disable the keep-alive for TCP connections coming from load balancer to my sailsjs server. So basically I would like to turn off the HTTP keep-alive. Right now my server responds with header

```
connection →keep-alive
```

I was wondering if there is a specific setting I need to tweak in the sails server to make this go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sails side you have two options, both include setting a HTTP header to close the connection instead of the default keep-alive .

**Option 1:**
Set the header at controller level by adding the code below before your actual response. This gives greater control as you can decide which specific controller closes the connection:

```
res.set("Connection", "close");
```

**Option 2:**
Alternatively, you can set the header at middleware level for all connections.

To do this, open config/http.js, create a new function inside the middleware object to set the header eg. setHeaderClose, then uncomment the order array and add a reference to the above function.

```
order: [
    'setHeaderClose',
    'startRequestTimer',
    'cookieParser',
    'session',
    'myRequestLogger',
    'bodyParser',
    'handleBodyParserError',
    'compress',
    'methodOverride',
    'poweredBy',
    '$custom',
    'router',
    'www',
    'favicon',
    '404',
    '500'
],

setHeaderClose: function(req, res, next) {
    res.set("Connection", "close");
    next();
}
```